# Tricky XSL Problem -- Determining Position in Complex Array

Tags: xml, xslt, indexing, siblings

```
        <row>
             <cell>Phrase 1</cell> #0
                <check shuffle="False">
                    <option key="1"/> #1
                    <option key="0"/> #2
                    <option key="0"/> #3
                    <option key="0"/> #4
                    <option key="0"/> #5
                    <option key="0"/> #6
                </check>
                <cell>Phrase 2</cell> #7
                <cell>Phrase 3</cell> #8
                <check shuffle="False">
                    <option key="1"/> #9
                    <option key="0"/> #10
                    <option key="0"/> #11
                    <option key="0"/> #12
                    <option key="0"/> #13
                    <option key="0"/> #14
                </check>
            </row>
```

I've got the following quandary.

I need to find the "index" in the "row" tag for both cells and the each option.

How do I do this in XSL? Each cell counts as one and each "option" children tags in any siblings also count. I've labeled the "indexes" I would like to retrieve. I realize there will probably be one way for determining the index of a "cell" versus a "option" element.

I know a bit about XSL but just enough to get my in trouble and quite frustrated. Any help  is appreciated.

Thanks as always SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`xsl:number`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cell|option">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vPosition">
            <xsl:number count="cell|option" level="any" from="row" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$vPosition - 1"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input (more `row`s):

```
<table>
    <row>
        <cell>Phrase 1</cell> #0                 
        <check shuffle="False">
            <option key="1"/> #1                     
            <option key="0"/> #2                     
            <option key="0"/> #3                     
            <option key="0"/> #4                     
            <option key="0"/> #5                     
            <option key="0"/> #6                 
        </check>
        <cell>Phrase 2</cell> #7                 
        <cell>Phrase 3</cell> #8                 
        <check shuffle="False">
            <option key="1"/> #9                     
            <option key="0"/> #10                     
            <option key="0"/> #11                     
            <option key="0"/> #12                     
            <option key="0"/> #13                     
            <option key="0"/> #14                 
        </check>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Phrase 1</cell> #0
        <check shuffle="False">
            <option key="1"/> #1
            <option key="0"/> #2
            <option key="0"/> #3
        </check>
        <cell>Phrase 2</cell> #4
        <check shuffle="False">
            <option key="1"/> #5
            <option key="0"/> #6
        </check>
        <cell>Phrase 3</cell> #7
    </row>
</table>
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <row>
        <cell>Phrase 1</cell>0 #0                 
        <check shuffle="False">
            <option key="1"></option>1 #1                     
            <option key="0"></option>2 #2                     
            <option key="0"></option>3 #3                     
            <option key="0"></option>4 #4                     
            <option key="0"></option>5 #5                     
            <option key="0"></option>6 #6                 
        </check>
        <cell>Phrase 2</cell>7 #7                 
        <cell>Phrase 3</cell>8 #8                 
        <check shuffle="False">
            <option key="1"></option>9 #9                     
            <option key="0"></option>10 #10                     
            <option key="0"></option>11 #11                     
            <option key="0"></option>12 #12                     
            <option key="0"></option>13 #13                     
            <option key="0"></option>14 #14                 
        </check>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>Phrase 1</cell>0 #0
        <check shuffle="False">
            <option key="1"></option>1 #1
            <option key="0"></option>2 #2
            <option key="0"></option>3 #3
        </check>
        <cell>Phrase 2</cell>4 #4
        <check shuffle="False">
            <option key="1"></option>5 #5
            <option key="0"></option>6 #6
        </check>
        <cell>Phrase 3</cell>7 #7
    </row>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question. Is it that in an XSLT stylesheet, while processing e.g. an `<option>` element, you want to output its index among other `<option>` and `<cell>` elements? For that, you want `<xsl:number>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <indices>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//cell | //option" mode="index"/>
        </indices>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="index">
        <index pos="{ position() - 1 }">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat( . , @key )"/>
        </index>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I picked a special `@mode` to highlight what's going on.

Note that `position()` is 1-based and acts upon the "current node-set", which is wort looking up in an XSLT textbook.